# How to create this overlapping UI in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

Trying to create an image button like this, only blue button is clickable

Answer (score 1):

**I have solved those issues in this way:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Demo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Hello'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNav(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Object1");
            }),
        floatingActionButtonLocation:
            FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked);
  }

  Widget _bottomNav() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 120.0,
      child: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
          shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: const Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Spacer(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 35,
              ),
              Text(
                "Capture",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ],
          ),),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of CircularNotchedRectangle()

Comment: welcome CrazyMind.